# ¿Cómo obtener el número de puntos dentro y fuera de un polígono por especie y exportarlo a un .csv?

Tags: r, csv

Tengo dos archivos:

El primero es un file.csv compuesto por 3 columnas: nombre de especie y las coordenadas geográficas (x, y). Las filas de este archivo son por lo tanto las ocurrencias/registros de las especies, por lo que una misma especie puede estar repetida en varias filas, pero no sus coordenadas geográficas. Este archivo cuenta con casi un millón de registros.

El segundo archivo es un file.shape que integra el área de distribución por especie. Un total de 4 mil y pico especies conforman este shapefile con sus áreas.

La variable común entre estos dos archivos es el nombre científico de la especie.

Necesito obtener a partir de estos archivos el conteo del número de ocurrencias/registros por especie que caen dentro del área de distribución de cada especie y el conteo de los que quedan fuera del área para la misma especie.

Hasta el momento he cargado las bases de datos y los he pasado a una proyección spatial:

```
# Ocurrencias
ocu<-read.csv2("file.csv", header=T, sep=";", dec=".")
ocu<-as.data.frame(ocu)
coordinates(ocu)<-c("decimallon","decimallat")
proj4string (ocu) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") 

# shapefile
shp <- readShapePoly("file.shp"[1],proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

La librería rgeos contiene una función gContains que me permite obtener el conteo de puntos dentro del polígono pero,

¿como procesar todo esto por especie para las tres mil y pico especies y que me devuelva un .csv con 3 variables: nombre de la especie, conteo de puntos fuera del área y el conteo de puntos dentro del área?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como mencionas, el paquete `rgeos` contiene una función para intersectar capas, pero en este caso el ejemplo puesto es con el paquete `spatialEco`, en principio hacen lo mismo. Al usar la función `point.in.poly` los campos del polígono migrarán a la capa de polígonos, por lo tanto te recomiendo hacer una copia de la capa de polígonos y sólo dejar el campo deseado -*especie*-.

El ejemplo que doy es súper básico, pero se extrapola a capas más complejas. Supongamos que tenemos los siguientes puntos y polígonos:

[image: ejemplo]

Donde el color rojo indica la especie de clase "1" y el color azul, la especie "2". Ambas capas tienen un campo de nombre `id`.

Debes intersectar ambas capas, luego agregar un campo (*test*) para evaluar si el punto se encuentra dentro o fuera usando una función lógica básica (entre el campo de especie de la capa de puntos y el mismo campo de la capa de polígonos).

Luego con la función `table` obtendrás una matriz con el resumen del conteo de observaciones dentro y fuera del área. Si bien el resultado justo el que necesitas, no se puede exportar directamente a un .csv desde este tipo de objeto.

Para convertir la tabla, se utiliza la función `as.data.frame.matrix`, la cual convertiría las columnas de la tabla, pero para conservar la etiqueta de las especies, debes antecederla de la función `row.names` sobre la tabla. Ambos objetos se juntan en un único data.frame. Puedes cambiar el nombre de las columnas para una mejor comprensión.

Finalmente eso lo exportas usando `write.csv`.

```
library(sp)
library(spatialEco)

inter <- point.in.poly(ocu,shp)

# Ubicación
inter@data$test <- inter$id == inter$id.1
tabla.resumen <- table(inter$id, inter$test)

final <- data.frame(rownames(tabla.resumen),as.data.frame.matrix(tabla.resumen))
names(final) <- c("sp","fuera.area","dentro.area")

final
  sp fuera.area dentro.area
1  1          2           6
2  2          3           7

write.csv(final,"ruta/conteo_especies.csv")
```